# Looking for a DateTime attribute

Tags: c#

Is there a possibility to decorate a DateTime property with an attribute, so in the designer when I input seconds they are also displayed.
Lets say for example when I input a date and time like: 31/10/2016 10:12:15
it gets always truncated to : 31/10/2016 10:12

Comment: do you mean when you display it in textbox? have you tried something like this `dt.ToString("MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss");`

Comment: Which designer? Are you using a PropertyGrid object?

Comment: Not sure about the "in the designer" part, but the [DebuggerDisplayAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x810d419.aspx) might be what you are looking for if you need a special format in the debugger.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? Maybe a screenshot of what you would expect?

Comment: Please tag your environment or UI framework: WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET WebForms, ASP.NET MVC, ...

Comment: https://imagebin.ca/v/30MKj6BXI2ae

Comment: @Ron just write your own TypeConverter and decorate that property, that's enough